# how to Identify the root child nodes?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

how to identify is this node is child of root node in Jtree in java swing. 
Ex:

```
Root
  |> Parent1
       |> Child1
  |> Parent2
       |> Child 2
       |> Child 3
```

Here i ll select any one node in that i want to know is the child of root node.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [TreeNode API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeNode.html) and you'll find the `getParent()` that will get your node's parent node. If the parent is null -- you're at the root.

You can also call `getRoot()` on the the JTree's model that will return the root node. Check the [TreeModel API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html) for more on this.

Comment: Thanks for your response. i want to know parent of the selected tree node.    tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent()    of Parent node

Comment: @Babu: OK, so where are you stuck exactly?